# Using strpos to check the existence of substring

Tags: php, strpos

I am trying to exclude those tweets which are not having `RT @` in their text.
Here is my code:

```
    foreach ($tweets3 as $item)
    {
            $text = $item->text;
            $check = 'RT @';
            $result = strpos($text, $check);
            if($result == false)
                    continue;
}
```

But these tweets also get excluded

```
Mention text : RT @IBMcloud: A few #cloud highlights from the @IBM Annual Report. Read more: http://t.co/TJBHoX3vdU http://t.co/fG66SE7kV1 

RT @holgermu: MyPOV - Nice way to put out our annual report in an interactive (engaging?) format - here is @IBM's - http://t.co/TIqi0soc5W 

RT @TopixPolitix: Chinese State and Citizens Must Battle Airpocalypse Together http://t.co/nV5TGJG6Fl - http://t.co/cln83ufDnk
```

**Though they have `RT @` in their text. Why?**

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`. From the PHP docs "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."

Answer (score 1):

See this warning in the [documentation for `strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

As the documentation says, `strpos()` can return values that evaluate to boolean `FALSE`. For example, `strpos()` will return `0` if there is a match at the beginning of the string.

To avoid ambiguity, always use strict comparison (`===`) instead of loose comparison (`==`) (whenever possible):

```
foreach ($tweets3 as $item)
{
    $text = $item->text;
    $check = 'RT @';
    $result = strpos($text, $check);

    // if "RT @" text not found in tweet, skip to next iteration
    if ($result === false) continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is flipped. `$result` will hold the numerical value if the text is found. You want your check to be:

```
        if($result !== false)
                continue;
```